# вылезает ошибка 'Unknown function makeDate'

Tags: clickhouse

Сам запрос:

```
select makeDate(23, toMonth(toDate(buy_date, 'dd/MM/yyy')), 1) as month, 
       avg(check_amount) as avg_check, 
       quantilesExactExclusive(0.5)(check_amount) as median_check 
from default.view_checks
group by month
```

Проблема возникает с функцией makeDate. Необходимо имеющийся месяц преобразовать в полную дату, год и день могут быть одинаковыми. В 'toMonth(toDate(buy_date, 'dd/MM/yyy'))' я как раз получаю этот месяц. Но makeDate не работает, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А версия кликхауса какая? `makeDate` появилась в 22.4